# Can memory transportation and kernel execution run in the same time on OpenCL

Tags: opencl

As I know, CUDA has a stream function. It make it possible that memory transportation and kernel execution  **run in the same**. Of course, the data in memory transportation and kernel execution is **different**.  Can I do this things with OpenCL. Beacuse sometime when you do some processing on video. the bottleneck is the memory transportation .

Comment: See the oclCopyComputeOverlap example in the OpenCL SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can overlap memory operations and kernel execution in OpenCL. Just set the `blocking_read` parameter of the `clEnqueueReadBUffer` function to `CL_FALSE`. But you need to make sure that the transfer has been completed before you operate on the data. Use events for that.